# select * from two tables with same column names mySQL

Tags: mysql

Let us say I have two tables with many columns so I do not want to name the column names explicitly in my query but i want to avoid duplicate names.

If I do:

```
  CREATE TABLE new_table
    SELECT a.*, b.*
    FROM  table1 a
    INNER JOIN table2 b ON a.myID = b.myId
    WHERE a.age > 10 and b.ice = 'melted'
```

I will get an error saying: `duplicate column name myId`, I could also get more errors if more column names in a and b are the same.

How can I avoid this issue by automatically adding a prefix to all column names in a.* and b.* w/o explicitly mentioning all the column names - very tedious to do so!

Thanks!

Comment: You'll have to alias your columns, OP, which means writing them out. Perhaps you can figure out a really quick way to list all of the columns in both tables with commas between them?

Comment: It is considered a bad (even if rather common) practice to select with `SELECT *` anyway; it opens you up to all sort of issues (such as this "randomly" breaking a query using tables with no column names in common when such a column later gets added to one of the tables used). _...and any half-decent query editor should be capable of spitting out a column list to save you the typing._

Comment: @Uueerdo younger coders will remember this as the time that computers worked for computers and not for humans... but yeah makes sense.  When you have 100s of columns this get's to be a rather suboptimal way to do things.  I could easily imagine a world where the SQL language can understand queries of this type and adds a prefix to each column name

Comment: I'm not sure what coder age has to do with any of it, but `SELECT *` will continue to be a bad and lazy practice until computers literally become psychic. If anything, this will be the age when even coders began expecting computers to think for them.

Comment: @Uueerdo * is not lazy at all, it's convenient which is very different.  what if you could do this in SQL language p.* as p.p_* and that means (explicitly defined in the SQL language) take all columns names and change them to p_<column_name>.  That's lazy? No, that's just convenient.  I guess I imagine a world where AI is also incorporated into coding so programming becomes more flexible.  Just because it has never been done doesn't mean will never be done.  We used to have to define types in all languages (e..g C) then python came and one doesn't have to define the type.  Programming evolves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience ORMs will run an initial DESCRIBE query so it can do this sort of stuff for you once it has the column names. But if you insist on doing it dynamically in a single query, you could do this with pure MySQL:

```
-- config
SET @database = 'your_database';
SET @tableA = 'table1';
SET @tableB = 'table2';

-- table alias "a" columns
SET @fieldsA = NULL;
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('a.', COLUMN_NAME), ' AS ',CONCAT('`a.', COLUMN_NAME,'`')) INTO @fieldsA
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = @database AND TABLE_NAME = @tableA;

-- table alias "b" columns
SET @fieldsB = NULL;
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('b.', COLUMN_NAME), ' AS ',CONCAT('`b.', COLUMN_NAME,'`')) INTO @fieldsB
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = @database AND TABLE_NAME = @tableB;

-- some variables for readability
SET @fields = CONCAT(' ', @fieldsA, ',', @fieldsB,' ');
SET @tableAliasA = CONCAT(' ',@database, '.', @tableA,' a ');
SET @tableAliasB = CONCAT(' ',@database, '.', @tableB,' b ');


-- generate our final query
SET @query = CONCAT('CREATE TABLE new_table SELECT', @fields,
                     'FROM', @tableAliasA,
                     'INNER JOIN', @tableAliasB,
                     'ON a.myID = b.myId WHERE a.age > 10 and b.ice = ''melted''');

-- finally run the query:
PREPARE stmt1 FROM @query;
EXECUTE stmt1;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;

-- if you have problems with the above query, uncomment the following to get the query so you can run it separately
-- SELECT @query;
```

I'd strongly advise against using this sort of solution though. I'd sooner run an initial DESCRIBE query as earlier stated, then generate your query based on that.  Another solution is to create a temporary table as a copy of the second table, then rename problematic columns, then proceed to join on it to produce the data you need to create your new_table. MySQL has no issues with result columns having the same name, the issue here is trying to create a table with two columns with the same name. So essentially what you're trying to do is a star select but excluding a column.

Another approach is to just select only the primary key from both:
`` SELECT a.myID as `aId`, b.myId as `bId` `` then create your table containing only that.  Then if you ever need data from a particular table, just LEFT JOIN on it to grab the information you're looking for. You can take this a step further and set up a VIEW to do this sort of thing for you. VIEWs can join tables for you and make it very easy to select whatever columns you're looking for. You can also setup multiple VIEWs as well. Also note that views behave just like tables for the purpose of joins. You can JOIN a view with a table, or you can join a view with a view, etc.

So rather than do what you're trying to do -- creating a new table with the data from two other tables -- consider whether you're actually looking for a [VIEW](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-view.html).

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, you will have to list the columns in case table have matching column names. However, you can use `information_schema` to get the column names, format those and copy paste in the query to save the pain, e.g.:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('a.', COLUMN_NAME)
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'schema' AND TABLE_NAME = 'table';
```

The above query should give you comma separated column names with `a.` prefix. You can then use the same query for table b, get the names out and use it in the main `SELECT` query.

**Update**

As @Uueerdo has rightly said, you can add alias to columns as well, e.g.:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('a.', COLUMN_NAME, ' AS a_', COLUMN_NAME))
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'schema' AND TABLE_NAME = 'table';
```

Comment: I'd say if you're going to do something like this take it a step further and do `GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('a.', COLUMN_NAME, ' AS a_', COLUMN_NAME))`

Comment: @darshan is there a way to do that in one single nested query to achieve the final objective?

Comment: @Dnaiel you can do that, however, it's complicated. Have a look at [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html). I would rather advise you to store the result in one query and use it in second.